# How to filter a column with list of elements in Python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
ID     Col_1
1      Apple, Cherry, Banana
2      Apple, Mango
3      Kiwi, Cherry
4      Apple, Cherry, Pear
5      Apple, Melon
6      Papaya, Cherry
```

I want to filter the data frame in these 3 ways:

1. Col_1 has both Apple & Cherry
2. Col_1 has Apple but not Cherry
3. Col_1 has Cherry but not Apple

This is how my output looks like:

```
1. Col_1 has both Apple & Cherry   

Output:
ID     Col_1
1      Apple, Cherry, Banana
4      Apple, Cherry, Pear


2. Col_1 has Apple but not Cherry

Output:
ID     Col_1
2      Apple, Mango
5      Apple, Melon

3. Col_1 has Cherry but not Apple

Output:
ID     Col_1
3      Kiwi, Cherry
6      Papaya, Cherry
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first start by creating OP's dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                        'Col_1': ['Apple, Cherry, Banana', 'Apple, Mango', 'Kiwi, Cherry', 'Apple, Cherry, Pear', 'Apple, Melon', 'Papaya, Cherry']})

[Out]:
   ID                  Col_1
0   1  Apple, Cherry, Banana
1   2           Apple, Mango
2   3           Kiwi, Cherry
3   4    Apple, Cherry, Pear
4   5           Apple, Melon
5   6         Papaya, Cherry
```

Based on what OP shared, considering that the constraints are always dependent on `apple` and `cherry`, one can create a function, let's call it `filter_df`, that takes as input a dataframe and two strings as follows

```
def filter_df(df, s1, s2):

    # Col_1 has both Apple & Cherry
    df1 = df[df['Col_1'].str.contains(s1) & df['Col_1'].str.contains(s2)]

    # Col_1 has Apple but not Cherry
    df2 = df[df['Col_1'].str.contains(s1) & ~df['Col_1'].str.contains(s2)]

    # Col_1 has Cherry but not Apple
    df3 = df[df['Col_1'].str.contains(s2) & ~df['Col_1'].str.contains(s1)]

    return df1, df2, df3
```

Then, if one applies the function `filter_df` to the dataframe `df`, with the strings `Apple` and `Cherry`, one gets the following results

```
df1, df2, df3 = filter_df(df, 'Apple', 'Cherry')

# df1 - Col_1 has both Apple & Cherry

[Out]:
   ID                  Col_1
0   1  Apple, Cherry, Banana
3   4    Apple, Cherry, Pear


# df2 - Col_1 has Apple but not Cherry

[Out]:
   ID         Col_1
1   2  Apple, Mango
4   5  Apple, Melon


# df3 - Col_1 has Cherry but not Apple

[Out]:
   ID           Col_1
2   3    Kiwi, Cherry
5   6  Papaya, Cherry
```

If one wants to change the strings to consider, for example, `Kiwi` and `Mango`, or other strings, one can do that as well. Also, if the conditions change in the future, one can easily adjust the function `filter_df` accordingly.